# SELECT SUM data rank and Resource id #9 error PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, sum, ranking

I have a website in which logged in members are stored under a table called ‘users’

‘users’ table

```
users_sales_guild_id | users_first_name | users_surname
555                  | Jane             | Smith
333                  | John             | Smith
111                  | Mike             | Myers
```

The users have sales data in a 'sales_points' field which is in a separate table called ‘sales_list’.

‘sales_list’ table

```
sales_id |  users_sales_guild_id     |  sales_points    |  sales_entry_date
1        |  555                      |  50              |  2013-02-31 00:00:00
2        |  333                      |  30              |  2013-02-31 00:00:00
3        |  111                      |  10              |  2013-02-31 00:00:00
4        |  555                      |  50              |  2013-03-31 00:00:00
5        |  333                      |  30              |  2013-03-31 00:00:00
6        |  111                      |  10              |  2013-03-31 00:00:00
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is a query which:

A. Calculates the total amount of 'sales_points' for each user from 'sales_list'

B. Lists 100 users with the user having the most points at the top, then ranking the next highest below and so on...

C. Im not after a ranking number, just the order itself.

With the code below I am getting 100 users printing ok, however I am getting a ‘Resource id #9’ message in the ’Total Points’ column when it prints. Can anyone help?

What I am trying to print

```
Jane Smith   |   100
John Smith   |   60
Mike Myers   |   20
```

Code:

```
    <?php 
    require_once ('config.inc.php');

    $page_title = '';
    include ('header.html');

    if (!isset($_SESSION['users_id'])) {

      $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
        . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
       // Check for a trailing slash.
       if ((substr($url, -1) == '/') OR (substr($url, -1) == '\\') ) {
            $url = substr ($url, 0, -1); // Chop off the slash.
       }
       // Add the page.
       $url .= 'login.php'; 

    ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
    header("Location: $url"); 
    exit(); // Quit the script.
    }?>

    <h1>Rankings</h1>

    <?php require_once ('database.php'); // Connect to the database.

    $total = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(sales_points) FROM sales_list,users WHERE sales_list.users_sales_guild_id = users.users_sales_guild_id
    AND sales_entry_date
    BETWEEN '2013-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-11-30 23:59:59'
    " ); 

    $query = "SELECT us.users_id, us.dealership_id, us.users_sales_guild_id, us.users_first_name, us.users_surname, us.users_type, 
             de.dealership_id, de.users_dealer_name, de.class , de.region, de.state, de.users_dealer_code_id, de.users_dealer_code_new_id, de.users_model, de.pma
             FROM users AS us, dealerships AS de 
             WHERE us.dealership_id = de.dealership_id
             ORDER BY ’$total’ DESC 
             LIMIT 100";

    $result = @mysql_query ($query); 

    // Table header.
    echo '<table  width="680"cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" style="font-size:12px;">
    <tr class="orangehead">
    <td align="center"><b>Member</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b>Title</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b>Dealer</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b>Category</a></b></td>
    <td align="center"><b>Dealer Code</a></b></td>
    <td align="center"><b>Total Points</a></b></td>
    </tr>';

    // Fetch and print all the records. echo '<td align="left"><strong>' . $row['sp_invoice_no'] . '</strong></td> ';

    $bg = '#ffffff'; // Set the background color.
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        $bg = ($bg=='#eaeced' ? '#ffffff' : '#eaeced'); // Switch the background color.   New: ' . $row['users_sales_guild_new_id'] . '
        // $entries = floor($row['sp_entry_amount']/200);
        echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bg . '">';           
        echo '<td align="left"><strong>' . $row['users_first_name'] . ' ' . $row['users_surname'] . '</strong></td> ';  
        echo '<td align="center">' . $row['users_type'] . ' </td>';     
        echo '<td align="center"> ' . $row['users_dealer_name'] . ' </td>';     
        echo '<td align="center"> ' . $row['class'] . ' </td>';     
        echo  '<td align="center"> ' . $row['users_sales_guild_id'] . ' </td>';     
        echo  '<td align="center"> ' . $total . '</td>';    
        echo  '</tr>
        ';
        }

    echo '</table>';

    mysql_free_result ($result); // Free up the resources.

    mysql_close(); // Close the database connection.    

    include ('footer.html'); // Include the HTML footer.
    ?>
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET - maybe go with a number lower than 100 for now!

Answer (score 1):

You don't fetch you first result. Fetch it as an array ([`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)) for example.

```
// Execute query
$total_query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(sales_points)
                      FROM sales_list, users
                      WHERE sales_list.users_sales_guild_id = users.users_sales_guild_id
                      AND sales_entry_date
                      BETWEEN '2013-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-11-30 23:59:59'");

// Fetch result
$total = mysql_fetch_array($total_query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You echo this:

```
$total = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(sales_points) FROM sales_list,users WHERE sales_list.users_sales_guild_id = users.users_sales_guild_id
    AND sales_entry_date
    BETWEEN '2013-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-11-30 23:59:59'
    " );
```

The variable `$total` contains the result of the query, which is a Resource. You should use mysql_fetch_assoc or a similar function to extract the result itself. It's best to give the `SUM(sales_points)` an alias, i.e. `AS total_sales_points` so you can fetch is easily.

By the way, the mysql_*-extension is soon-to-be [deprecated](https://www.php.net/mysql_query). Good alternatives include [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(sales_points) as points FROM sales_list,users WHERE sales_list.users_sales_guild_id = users.users_sales_guild_id
    AND sales_entry_date
    BETWEEN '2013-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-11-30 23:59:59'
    " );
$row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
$total = $row->points;
```

You are echoing the mysql resource, you first need to fetch the results, then you can echo them.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for replying. This option was the closest however there was an issue, it displayed the total points for all of the users combined and not the individual user. So using the example above it printed Jane Smith | 180, John Smith | 180 , Mike Myers 180. I'll try to fix this but if anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: Add `GROUP BY users.users_sales_guild_id` at the end of your query